# What happens if I call fork() inside main?

Tags: c, fork

Simple piece of code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

main()
{
     printf("Process");
     fork();
     fork();
     return 0;
}
```

From my understanding of    fork(), after this code executes we will have 3 child processes and 1 parent process. Also whenever we call fork() the execution should start from the statement immediately after the fork() statement. Hence according to me *"Process"* should be printed only once. But in my output *Process* is being printed 4 times. How is that possible?

Comment: Yes so it seems. Shall I delete this or let it be?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because the standard output is line buffered by default, when you call `fork()`, the output buffer is inherited by all the children processes.

There are several different ways to change this behavior:

Add a new line character at the end:

```
printf("Process\n");
```

or call `fflush()` to flush the output:

```
printf("Process");
fflush(stdout);
```

or change standard output to not buffered using [`setbuf()` or `setvbuf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/setbuf.3.html):

```
setbuf(stdout, NULL);
printf("Process");
```

Using either way, you'll see the output only once.

Note: see [@Dvaid Schwartz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22008687/1009479) for the bug with calling `atexit()` multiple times in your code.

Comment: This doesn't actually fix the bug. It just changes the code from "having a horrible bug that causes it do the wrong thing" to "having a horrible bug that happens to cause no harm by luck". It explains his results, but not the underlying problem (that atexit handlers run four times) nor does it tell him how to fix the underlying problem.

Answer (score 4):

Your program has a bug. *All* the children return from `main`, causing [atexit](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/functions/atexit.html) handlers to run four times. The children should call `_exit`.

Here's how your code should look:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>

main()
{
     int is_child = 0; 
     printf("Process");

     if (fork() == 0) 
        is_child = 1; 

     if (fork() == 0) 
        is_child = 1;

     if (is_child)
        _exit(0);

     return 0;
}
```

Comment: And if child needs to print something to stdout, it ...

Comment: Okay I see. What kind of adverse effects can this sort of bug cause?

Comment: Can you explain why repeated invocation of such handlers is such a bad thing?

Comment: @user3125367 Ask your own question. I'll be happy to explain how to do that correctly. It requires the parent's cooperation. What you can do after a `fork` and before an `exec` is limited and must be carefully orchestrated because you share some resources with the parent.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit This program is as good an example as any. But imagine a program that writes to a file or network connection. Duplicate invocation of an atexit handler can result in the data being written twice.

Comment: @bigbong You never know. It depends what the atexit handlers do. It may work just fine until some library changes somewhere else completely and then horrible things happen.

Comment: Please extend this answer, if possible.

Comment: From docs :"The function _exit() is like exit(3), but does not call any functions
       registered with atexit(3) or on_exit(3).  Whether it flushes standard
       I/O buffers and removes temporary files created with tmpfile(3) is
       implementation-dependent."  As it is implementation-dependent whether it flushes I/O buffers, does it mean the parent still has to call flush() to avoid writing twice ?

Comment: @Dabo ["Open streams shall not be flushed."](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/_exit.html)

Comment: @David Okay so it's a general risk and not something specific to the handler mechanism itself.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit The basic idea is that returning from `main` or calling `exit` in a child causes the library to perform the on-termination operations for the original process, even though it hasn't terminated. That can do any amount of damage, depending on what those termination behaviors are. It's a bug.

Comment: See this is why I vastly prefer spawning threads to forking into child processes. Of course that's not always appropriate.