# Ambiguity about fork() in gcc compiler

Tags: c, gcc, fork

The following two codes are compiled and executed using the gcc compiler
code1:

```
    main()
    {
     printf("Before FORK\n");
     fork();
     printf("After FORK \n\n");
    }
```

code 2:

```
    main()
    {
     printf("Before FORK");
     fork();
     printf("After FORK \n\n");
    }
```

The code1 prints "Before FORK" statement once but the code2 prints the same twice. Please explain the reason behind that.

Comment: yes it's a duplicate, but unintentional

Comment: I did not assume that you *intentionally* post a duplicate question! But this has been asked and answered frequently, and all I did was to Google for "printf fork" :-)

Comment: In my opinion best answer for this was givven [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22008504/2549281) by David Schwartz

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`stdout` is line-buffered by default when associated with a terminal. In example 2, add `fflush(stdout)` after the first `printf` to  flush `stdout`.